# Why won't this c++ code compile?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Seeig that i'm new to C++ I thought i'd try and write a very simple console app that populates a 2D-array and displays its contents.

But the code I've written won't compile.

Some of the errors I get are:

**error C2065: 'box' : undeclared identifier**
**error C2228: left of '.GenerateBox' must have class/struct/union**

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Box box;
  box.GenerateBox();
}

class Box
{
private:
  static int const maxWidth = 135;
  static int const maxHeight = 60; 
  char arrTest[maxWidth][maxHeight];

public:
    void GenerateBox()
    {
      for (int i=0; i<maxHeight; i++)
        for (int k=0; k<maxWidth; k++)
        {
          arrTest[i][k] = 'x';
        }

      for (int i=0; i<maxHeight; i++)
      {
        for (int k=0; k<maxWidth; k++)
        {
          cout << arrTest[i][k];
        }
           cout << "\n";
      }
    }
};
```

Any idea whats causing these errors?

Comment: +1 for including a complete sample program copy-pasted directly from your source code. See why that matters at http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Rob: +1 for good to read website referenced :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ compiler reads source files in a single pass, from top to bottom. You have described the Box class at the bottom, after main(), after the part where you attempt to use the class. Accordingly, when the compiler gets to the part where you say 'Box box;', it has not yet seen the class definition, and thus has no idea what 'Box' means.

Comment: If he were using pointers a predeclaration of Box could be used to make it work with the box definition below. But no such luck in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Move the `main` function to the bottom of your code. Specifically, you need to define `Box` before you reference it.

The only time when you can get away with only a forward declaration (i.e. `class Box;`) is when you just use `Box` as a pointer or reference.

Comment: but if you use forward declarations, make sure you remember to define the Box class later or you will get runtime exceptions when your code tries to use the class

Comment: Not really. Forward declarations allow your code to treat the object like an generic pointer. You won't be able to call any member functions. The code that actually instantiates the object or calls its function WILL need to have the full declaration, or else it won't compile.

Answer (score 5):

You have to define Box before using it. So for your small test you can put your class definition before the main.

For bigger programs, you will put your class definitions inside .h header files that you will include at the top of your source files.

Comment: He must 'define' the class, not just declare it.

Comment: true.."for historical reasons, a class definition is often referred to as a class declaration" but it's not correct

Comment: @Nikko: to makes things worse, every definition is a declaration, so it's technically true but very unhelpful to refer to a class definition as a class declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Is due to pre declaration of main(). Use main after declaration of class Box.

Answer (score 0):

@nikko is right. You have to declare the Box class before using it.By either

- cutting pasting the declaration

  or telling the compiler you will declare them later

try this

```
extern class Box;
//use box class here
//then define it later as you wish
```